# docker; invalid reference format

Tags: docker

> I tried to create a mongo-express container using the command below:

```
docker run -d \
-p 8081:8081 \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME =mongoadmin \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD =secret \
--net mongo-network \
--name mongo-express \
-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER =mongodb \
mongo-express
```

> And got the error:

```
docker: invalid reference format.
```

Comment: You have some erroneous spaces in your command line. Instead of `-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME =mongoadmin` you need to write `-e ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=mongoadmin` (and similarly for your other environment variables).

Comment: Thanks a lot, your suggestion worked.